# Getting RequireJS to work with .tpl

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I'm relatively new to RequireJS and I have a problem that is probably a simple fix - In most instances I'm loading .js files, but one of my files loads templates with the .tpl extension and I'd like it not to automatically append .js (and end up trying to load `mytemplate.tpl.js`).

Is there a simple way to tell RequireJS (in one file only) to not do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `noext` requirejs plugin.

You can find it here: https://github.com/millermedeiros/requirejs-plugins

```
require.config({
    paths : {
        //create alias to plugins (not needed if plugins are on the baseUrl)
        noext: 'lib/requirejs-plugins/noext',
    }
});

require([
    noext!pathto/mytemplate.tpl
], ...)
```

Comment: i tried using your sol for the similar problem i was facing. it gave me "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <". when i looked up i saw that the noext plugin does not use define, hence returns that error..